# Fill the screen with 2 RadioButtons?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

How to fill a ConstraintLayout with two radioButtons inside of a RadioGroup? I can't find a way to do it. I post here two images, one is how I want to make it look, and the other is how it looks right now with my code.

[This is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X3j4.png)

[This is how I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWLph.png)

```html
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout6">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Paypal"
                android:textAlignment="center" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Contrarreembolso"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing that I could do after reading some answers on StackOverflow and trying many things is to get to this point:

[image]

I have taken this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#193312"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:text="Paypal"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#122B33"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Contrarreembolso"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And used this code to get the height of the screen and put half of it on my views, inside your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Get the height is the screen
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    RadioButton radioButton1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    RadioButton radioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

    //Give view half of the screen height
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = radioButton1.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (height)/2;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2 = radioButton2.getLayoutParams();
    params2.height = (height)/2;

}
```

Notice that this layout is not perfect looking, your radio buttons do spread across your device in height but they are not equal, the one thing left to do if you want your button to be equal in height is to calculate the action bar height and take it into account.